# How to build Google breakpad on Windows with Qt Creator (gcc/MinGW)?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, mingw, qt-creator, google-breakpad

Given: Application project written for Qt Creator (4.7.4, Win32 only, gcc/MinGW).

Needed: Plug in well-known Google breakpad library to gather verbose crash dumps from customers.

My current findings are as follows:

- there is breakpad-qt project out there, about two years old. It contains subtree of upstream breakpad sources to be built with Qt Creator, so I've tried to produce working example by building it.
- breakpad itself inherently depends on `DbgHelp.h` from Windows SDK, because of usage of Microsoft minidump format.
- `DbgHelp.h` can be found in Windows SDK headers, but
  further includes some headers from Visual Studio, which are reportedly could not be compiled by GCC/MinGW (incompatible language extensions by MSVS compiler, I suppose).
- google breakpad includes MSVS solution files (produced by gyp), and is readily buildable by MSVS (I've succeeded with both 2008 and 2010 Express versions), producing some `.lib`s to be linked with target application.
- but the `.lib` files compiled above are not understood by MinGW `ld`, so could not be linked with Qt project. It is known incompatibility of library formats.
- though, `.lib` files from MSVS 2008 (and not 2010) are understood by `reimp` tool from MinGW tools (latest available), which is intended to translate libraries from MSVS format to MinGW usable format. In my case the symbols are exported seemingly correctly, and some `.obj` files too, but recompiled library (with `dlltool` of MinGW) is still unlinkable by MinGW `ld`.
- And all the fuss with `.lib` linkage is blocked with another problem: valid headers are required in Qt Project in order to compile client code, and these headers are exactly those from breakpad, including `DbgHelp.h`, see above!

Currently open alternatives I see:

- Entirely switch the application from Qt/MinGW (Creator) to Qt/MSVS, which could allow direct linking of upstream breakpad. I think this is the core of success of little googleable use cases of Qt + breakpad at all.
- Construct some some hybrid approach, where application is built as usual with Creator and later linked with breakpad by MSVS linker. But again, headers!
- Tear off a minimal closure of what breakpad needs from Microsoft headers in order to compile with pure Qt Creator.

Any suggestions, existing experiences?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you, but the QtBreakpad integration has not been developed for and tested with MinGW.

Comment: Well, this is quite not true, because of [breakpad-qt](https://github.com/AlekSi/breakpad-qt) project out there, and it is designed for Qt Creator.

Comment: Actually I was part of the team doing that :-). Qt Creator on Windows packages are built with MSVC. So if it works with MinGW, it's a mere coincidence.

Comment: Note you can build Qt Creator with MinGW, but some features will be disabled implicitly in doing so (e.g. also the Windows 7 taskbar integration, since MinGW is lacking the required headers).